# Как скомпилировать python - файл на tkinter в apk?

Tags: python, tkinter

У меня есть код, который написан на python. Для написания я использовал TKinter. Как скомпилировать код, чтобы APK-файл мог установить каждый?

Answer (score 1):

Сначала конвертируйте py в exe с помощью pyinstaller.А потом конвертируйте exe в apk.Есть куча вариантов в гугле на тем: exe в apk converter.Можно использовать [эту](https://apkbucket.net/exe-to-apk-converter-apk-for-android/) программу.